# How to set null value to Datetimepicker when load?

Tags: vb.net

I have a `Datetimepicker1`, i want to set it to empty when load, and show value after chose.
I have found a code

```
Datetimepicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
Datetimepicker1.CustomFormat = " "
```

but it does not show value after chose.

Comment: I don't quite understand the question? What value is this suppose to show..?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean a datetime picker in a winforms application.

in your code, you can do the following:

string theDate = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString();

or, if you'd like to specify the format of the date:

string theDate = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

Answer (score 0):

DateTimePickers can't be set to null because DateTime can't be null, but you can set them to DateTime.MinValue which is the default value for an uninitialized DateTime. And then you just check if the dtp.Value = DateTime.MinValue and if so, treat it as null.

However, if you want to really distinguish when no value has been selected, the easiest way is to set DateTimePicker.ShowCheckBox to true, and then you check dtp.Checked and if it's true, you read the value, otherwise you treat it as a null.

Have you try this : for testing purpose

```
DateTime? myselectedDate = null;

private void DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) {

   myselectedDate = DateTimePicker1.Value;

}
```

And

```
this.dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
this.dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = " "; //a string with one whitespace
```

Comment: i don't understand this  `DateTime? myselectedDate = null;`

Comment: It is tagged as VB.NET not C#

Comment: but he is having tag c# if i avalilabe on caode vb so easily you have to change on c#. if you are a programmer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

DateTime? dateSample= null;

Comment: do i need to write it in EVENT ?

Answer (score 0):

DatetimePicker can't have no value. Null or default value is `DateTime.MinValue`. Your code changes the format in order to show nothing.

To show the date again, simply change `DateTimePicker.Format` again when needed:

```
DateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Long;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because , you formatted your datetimepicker "", you should write the below code in valuechanged event of the datetimepicker;

```
Datetimepicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.short(type which you need short,long etc..)
```